# How to set up JavaScript in .net framework mvc project

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Please can someone tell me some tutorial on how to configure javaScript in an MVC project in the .net framework, and have tried several without success, thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What exactly do you mean "configure JavaScript"?

Comment: You may find this link useful: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the App_Start folder there should be a "Bundle.cs" file. It wraps up all the Javascript and CSS files.

If you want to add your own javascript add it using the Bundle.cs class or put Javascript directly in the _Layout.cshtml file.